# How to create an enumerated map of classes, where the classes conform to a generic interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, factory-pattern

Most factory patterns I've seen in typescript are based on some named mapping between a name and the Class type.

A naive summary implementation:

```
const myMap = {
 classOne: ExampleClass,
 classTwo: AnotherClass
}

(k: string) => { return new myMap[k] }
```

I wanted to take this mapping idea up a notch - as my classes are of the form ExampleClass implements iGenericInterface<T>

However, I can't seem to specify that Record Value types should be limited to those that implement the iGenericInterface<T> In the example I am trying below the problem area is marked with ***

```
export interface iGenericInterface<K> {
  process(input: K): void
}

class ExampleClass implements iGenericInterface<string> {
  process(input: string): void {
    console.log(input);
  }
}

class AnotherClass implements iGenericInterface<number> {
  process(input: number): void {
    console.log(input);
  }
}

class UnsupportedClass {
  otherMethod(input: boolean): void {
    console.log(input);
  }
}

enum instantiableClassesEnum { class1, class2, class3 };
type enumValues = keyof typeof instantiableClassesEnum;
type logicStore<T> = Record<enumValues, ***iGenericInterface<T>***>

const classMap: logicStore<any> = {
    class1: ExampleClass,
    class2: AnotherClass,
    class3: UnsupportedClass,
};
```

I would expect the UnsupportedClass to be an error, but would like to have the others accepted by the compiler.

If I change the `ExampleClass` to an instance i.e. `class1: new ExampleClass` the compiler is happy - however, I am then not sure how to use the mapping in the factory method - `return new myMap[k]`

**EDIT - (@Adriaan This is NOT an answer, just a clarification of the end goal)**
Ability to create classes based on Enumeration input - using mapped structure above.

```
class LogicFactory {
  static createLogic<T>(logicClass: enumValues): 
  iGenericInterface<T> {
  return new classMap[logicClass]();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand the point of making `LogicStore` generic if your only example use is `LogicStore<any>`.  Nor do I see why `enum`s are involved, since you're only ever using the key and not the value.  But you're the boss, I guess.  So is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQR9N) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz, The goal - "Named construction of a class". My classes are generic "Example" and "Another" - string and number respectively. Based off the type iGenericInterface<T>. Now I need a mapping object. I chose to map between Enums and my classes. (This was the mistake - It needed to be mapped to the constructor type of my classes). So ultimately, I can pass in an enum and get the desired constructed Class. I have edited the answer to try and make it clearer. Than you so much for your attention.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @jcalz - sorry Adriaan just blew away my clarification. Will try and redo it.

Answer (score 2):

You need `Constructor<T>` type

```
type _builtin = InstanceType<any> // T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any) => T

enum instantiableClassesEnum { class1, class2, class3 };
type enumValues = keyof typeof instantiableClassesEnum;
type logicStore<T> = Record<enumValues, Constructor<iGenericInterface<T>>>

const classMap: logicStore<any> = {
    class1: ExampleClass,
    class2: AnotherClass,
    class3: UnsupportedClass, // Property 'process' is missing in type 'UnsupportedClass'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dimava answer - How to create the Enum - Constructor mapping. The end goal was achieved:

Here is the answer in the expanded context. @jcalz

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any) => T
enum instantiableClassesEnum { class1, class2, class3 };
type enumValues = keyof typeof instantiableClassesEnum;
type logicStore<T> = Record<enumValues, 
Constructor<iGenericInterface<T>>>

const classMap: logicStore<any> = {
    class1: ExampleClass,
    class2: AnotherClass,
    class3: UnsupportedClass,
};


class LogicFactory {
  static createLogic<T>(logicClass: enumValues): iGenericInterface<T> {
    return new classMap[logicClass]();
  }
}
```